# Sitemap for domain with multilanguage site

Tags: sitemap

I have `www.example.it` that support 2 language:

```
example.it/it => Italian language
example.it/en => English language
```

How can I set up the correct sitemap for the 2 version?

Comment: http://www.railshorde.com/blog/how-to-create-sitemap-for-multiple-language-site

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google have specifically answered this here:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/multilingual-and-multinational-site.html

For example:

```
<url>
  <loc>http://mysite.it/it</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://mysite.it/en" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="it" href="http://mysite.it/it" />
</url>
```

You will need to know the language or country code in order to be able to categorize other language types

http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/bllanguagecodes.htm

Comment: jnelson, as per the GWT link, should there be two url tags for the above e.g. one with <loc>http://mysite.it/it</loc> and the other with <loc>http://mysite.it/en</loc> or just one is enough?

Comment: It looks that way, although it's not clear without the example. From [Google Support:](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en) You must create a separate url element for each URL. Each url element must include a loc tag indicating the page URLs, and an xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="XX" subelement for every alternate version of the page, including itself.